# CSS grid with scrollbar in div-contaier

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to build an `HTML` page with the following structure:

```
(it's not actual `HTML` code, just to demonstrate the structure)
...
<body>
  <header> 
  <container>
    <content-container>
</body>
...
```

I'm using standard Grid from `CSS` and trying to figure out how could I get wished result. I stuck with the nested scrollable container (content-container), which shows me the y-scrollbar, but it doesn't work and the page shows the second (main) scrollbar which is working.

You can see my example here: https://angular-daidbs.stackblitz.io

This issue can be fixed if I set the height of the  statically to some value (100px let's say), but I want it to be after the header (automatically moved if header grows) and till the end of the page.

Card - styling for the items.

That's my current CSS:

```
.main-grid {
  display: grid; 
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr; 
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
}

.header {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid; 
  display: grid; 
  grid-template-columns: 1fr; 
  grid-template-rows: auto; 
  justify-items: center;
}

.content-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
  justify-items: center;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.card{
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

That's the view that I'm trying to build: in green the place where I would like to have a scrollbar.

[image]

Comment: "it doesn't work" is very vague.. please explain what is not working. And add your html here

Comment: you can checkout all the html at live example (link to stackblitz was provided). The idea is that container is showing the scrollbar, but it is non-active. Instead, I have a scrollbar for the whole page, which is working.

Comment: first of all add your generated html to the question... check this https://jsfiddle.net/xc2b5yrn/ if this solves your issue, will covert to answer, thanks!

Comment: so that solves your question?

Comment: looks like. I will test on my local with the real dynamic input, but I guess that's it !

Comment: also add your generated html to the question, maybe you can copy it from the fiddle above (copied it from https://angular-daidbs.stackblitz.io)

Answer (score 1):

Html + CSS solution satisfies your one requirement that you will get the scroll bars the way you want. However if the height of the header changes you will need JavaScript to calculate the height of the header div and then subtract it.

You do need to give height if you want to use `overflow-y: scroll`  property. In your case we can calculate the height of the `container` as (height of page - height of header). Using `vh` and `calc()` css function this can be achieved.

> edit1: Added the js to dynamically calculate the height of header.

```js
function cal_height() {
  var h_height = document.getElementById("header").offsetHeight;
  var container = document.getElementById("container");
  container.style.cssText = "height: calc(100vh - " + h_height + "px);";
}

window.onload = cal_height;
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;padding: 0;
}
header {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 30px;
}
.container { 
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.content-container {
  margin: 20px 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>

  <header id="header">This is a header</header>
  <div class="container" id="container">
    <div class="content-container">
      Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis quas delectus, amet ea, doloremque maxime ipsam voluptate harum quaerat sint corrupti praesentium. Ut et dicta ducimus dolore vitae odit! Est?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Fuga et veniam inventore mollitia quis voluptate odio consectetur quia tenetur, nemo error rem quae esse, cumque doloribus fugit! Autem, quod laboriosam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates tenetur, odio iusto impedit temporibus voluptas veniam necessitatibus consectetur ullam tempora, culpa, cumque dolores. Sit, incidunt repudiandae? Error ut ad maiores.
    </div>
    <div class="content-container">
        Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis quas delectus, amet ea, doloremque maxime ipsam voluptate harum quaerat sint corrupti praesentium. Ut et dicta ducimus dolore vitae odit! Est?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Fuga et veniam inventore mollitia quis voluptate odio consectetur quia tenetur, nemo error rem quae esse, cumque doloribus fugit! Autem, quod laboriosam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates tenetur, odio iusto impedit temporibus voluptas veniam necessitatibus consectetur ullam tempora, culpa, cumque dolores. Sit, incidunt repudiandae? Error ut ad maiores.
      </div>
      <div class="content-container">
          Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis quas delectus, amet ea, doloremque maxime ipsam voluptate harum quaerat sint corrupti praesentium. Ut et dicta ducimus dolore vitae odit! Est?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Fuga et veniam inventore mollitia quis voluptate odio consectetur quia tenetur, nemo error rem quae esse, cumque doloribus fugit! Autem, quod laboriosam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates tenetur, odio iusto impedit temporibus voluptas veniam necessitatibus consectetur ullam tempora, culpa, cumque dolores. Sit, incidunt repudiandae? Error ut ad maiores.
        </div>
    <div class="content-container">
      Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis quas delectus, amet ea, doloremque maxime ipsam voluptate harum quaerat sint corrupti praesentium. Ut et dicta ducimus dolore vitae odit! Est?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Fuga et veniam inventore mollitia quis voluptate odio consectetur quia tenetur, nemo error rem quae esse, cumque doloribus fugit! Autem, quod laboriosam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates tenetur, odio iusto impedit temporibus voluptas veniam necessitatibus consectetur ullam tempora, culpa, cumque dolores. Sit, incidunt repudiandae? Error ut ad maiores.
    </div>
    <div class="content-container">
      Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis quas delectus, amet ea, doloremque maxime ipsam voluptate harum quaerat sint corrupti praesentium. Ut et dicta ducimus dolore vitae odit! Est?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Fuga et veniam inventore mollitia quis voluptate odio consectetur quia tenetur, nemo error rem quae esse, cumque doloribus fugit! Autem, quod laboriosam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates tenetur, odio iusto impedit temporibus voluptas veniam necessitatibus consectetur ullam tempora, culpa, cumque dolores. Sit, incidunt repudiandae? Error ut ad maiores.
    </div>
    <div class="content-container">
      Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis quas delectus, amet ea, doloremque maxime ipsam voluptate harum quaerat sint corrupti praesentium. Ut et dicta ducimus dolore vitae odit! Est?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Fuga et veniam inventore mollitia quis voluptate odio consectetur quia tenetur, nemo error rem quae esse, cumque doloribus fugit! Autem, quod laboriosam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates tenetur, odio iusto impedit temporibus voluptas veniam necessitatibus consectetur ullam tempora, culpa, cumque dolores. Sit, incidunt repudiandae? Error ut ad maiores.
    </div>
    <div class="content-container">
      Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis quas delectus, amet ea, doloremque maxime ipsam voluptate harum quaerat sint corrupti praesentium. Ut et dicta ducimus dolore vitae odit! Est?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Fuga et veniam inventore mollitia quis voluptate odio consectetur quia tenetur, nemo error rem quae esse, cumque doloribus fugit! Autem, quod laboriosam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates tenetur, odio iusto impedit temporibus voluptas veniam necessitatibus consectetur ullam tempora, culpa, cumque dolores. Sit, incidunt repudiandae? Error ut ad maiores.
    </div>
    <div class="content-container">
        Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis quas delectus, amet ea, doloremque maxime ipsam voluptate harum quaerat sint corrupti praesentium. Ut et dicta ducimus dolore vitae odit! Est?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Fuga et veniam inventore mollitia quis voluptate odio consectetur quia tenetur, nemo error rem quae esse, cumque doloribus fugit! Autem, quod laboriosam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates tenetur, odio iusto impedit temporibus voluptas veniam necessitatibus consectetur ullam tempora, culpa, cumque dolores. Sit, incidunt repudiandae? Error ut ad maiores.
      </div>
    <div class="content-container">
      Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis quas delectus, amet ea, doloremque maxime ipsam voluptate harum quaerat sint corrupti praesentium. Ut et dicta ducimus dolore vitae odit! Est?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Fuga et veniam inventore mollitia quis voluptate odio consectetur quia tenetur, nemo error rem quae esse, cumque doloribus fugit! Autem, quod laboriosam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates tenetur, odio iusto impedit temporibus voluptas veniam necessitatibus consectetur ullam tempora, culpa, cumque dolores. Sit, incidunt repudiandae? Error ut ad maiores.
    </div>
    <div class="content-container">
      Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis quas delectus, amet ea, doloremque maxime ipsam voluptate harum quaerat sint corrupti praesentium. Ut et dicta ducimus dolore vitae odit! Est?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Fuga et veniam inventore mollitia quis voluptate odio consectetur quia tenetur, nemo error rem quae esse, cumque doloribus fugit! Autem, quod laboriosam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates tenetur, odio iusto impedit temporibus voluptas veniam necessitatibus consectetur ullam tempora, culpa, cumque dolores. Sit, incidunt repudiandae? Error ut ad maiores.
    </div>
    <div class="content-container">
      Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis quas delectus, amet ea, doloremque maxime ipsam voluptate harum quaerat sint corrupti praesentium. Ut et dicta ducimus dolore vitae odit! Est?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Fuga et veniam inventore mollitia quis voluptate odio consectetur quia tenetur, nemo error rem quae esse, cumque doloribus fugit! Autem, quod laboriosam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates tenetur, odio iusto impedit temporibus voluptas veniam necessitatibus consectetur ullam tempora, culpa, cumque dolores. Sit, incidunt repudiandae? Error ut ad maiores.
    </div>
    <div class="content-container">
      Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis quas delectus, amet ea, doloremque maxime ipsam voluptate harum quaerat sint corrupti praesentium. Ut et dicta ducimus dolore vitae odit! Est?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Fuga et veniam inventore mollitia quis voluptate odio consectetur quia tenetur, nemo error rem quae esse, cumque doloribus fugit! Autem, quod laboriosam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates tenetur, odio iusto impedit temporibus voluptas veniam necessitatibus consectetur ullam tempora, culpa, cumque dolores. Sit, incidunt repudiandae? Error ut ad maiores.
    </div>
            
  </div>

  <script src="js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: cool, thanks. So in this case, if I want to have dynamic change I need to provide a script which will listen onPageSizeChange , it will take current height of the header and based on the result modify height value for the container, right?

Comment: @Eugen Exactly it has to modify the height of the container because the header's height has been changed and if you do not modify the container height you will get an extra scroll bar. will try to edit this answer with the js solution if possible soon.

Comment: One this i did not understand is that in which case your header's height is gonna change? @Eugen

Answer (score 0):

For solution using CSS Grid:

```
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  border: 1px solid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
}

.header {
  background: #c0c0c0;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.content {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;  
  grid-gap: 10px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.card {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <p>Header</p>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="card">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It makes use of `overflow-y: scroll;`.

Full example: see [codepen](https://codepen.io/lumonald/pen/joVvdJ).